# StackExchange iOS app URL scheme?

Tags: support, ios-app

[Opener](http://www.opener.link/) can open StackExchange links. It uses the URL scheme, but I can't find it in the any details in the version history on the App Store about it.

Any details on this? I'd like to know what's URL, the syntax and possible parameters. It would be great if this information were accessible in the App Store description (… or the version history of the updates).

Answer (score 4):

I grabbed the info.plist file from the app, here's a relevant section:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLIconFile</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb222138527948326</string>
            <string>com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod</string>
            <string>se-zaphod</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod</string>
    </dict>
```

It looks like you're going to use a URL starting with `se-zaphod://`, but I don't know the specifics of the rest of the URL.

Comment: Zaphod Beeblebrox… that's too funny. Good idea, I've totally forgotten about the `.plist` trick. I'll wait another day to see if the support chimes in and shed any light on if it's possible to add a search parameter for that URL. I don't think that this is currently possible, so this answer is as good as checked'n'approved. Thanks @Undo.

Comment: It appears that the only thing that's been implemented at the time of writing is the ability to open links to questions (and answers) through passing the web link prepended with `se-zaphod://` (sans-`http://`). Other link types don't appear to do anything special: search pages don't even go to the correct site right now, let alone pass the search parameter.